# Does somebody knows how to create a valid ccnet.config file for cruise control?

Tags: .net, cruisecontrol.net

**Here is my configuration file:**

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
```

```
<name>NunitProject</name>

<sourcecontrol type="svn">

  <trunkUrl>https://192.168.1.176/svn/NunitProyect/trunk/</trunkUrl>

  <workingDirectory>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\NunitProject\WorkingDirectory</workingDirectory>

  <username>user</username>

  <password>password</password>

</sourcecontrol>

<tasks>

  <msbuild>

    <executable>
      C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe
    </executable>

    <workingDirectory>
      C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\NunitProject\WorkingDirectory
    </workingDirectory>

    <projectFile>NunitTest.sln</projectFile>

    <buildArgs>
      /noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=Debug /v:m

    </buildArgs>
  </msbuild>
</tasks>
```

**and here is the error:**

BUILD EXCEPTION 
Error Message: System.IO.IOException: Unable to execute file [C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\NunitProject\WorkingDirectory\svn].  The file may not exist or may not be executable. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: What are you asking? How to create a cc.net file or why is yours failing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sourcecontrol element needs an executable element inside of it that points to the location of svn.exe (wherever it may be installed in your system). Otherwise, it assumes that it is present in the working directory (generally a poor assumption).

Comment: +1 as nobody vote up for your exact answer (even the author !).

Comment: Much appreciated. That was the first time I ever got a correct answer without an upvote…